# Size comparison between Tuple and List

Tags: python, list, types, tuples, sizeof

Why the size of the 2nd list decreased with the increase of the element 'XYZ'?, In the case of the tuple, it increased as expected.

```
import sys
l1 = [1,2,3,4, "Quant Tading", "Python"]
t1 = (1,2,3,4, "Quant Tading", "Python")
print(sys.getsizeof(l1)) #output 152
print(sys.getsizeof(t1)) #output 88

import sys
l1 = [1,2,3,4, "Quant Tading", "Python", "xyz"]
t1 = (1,2,3,4, "Quant Tading", "Python", "xyz")
print(sys.getsizeof(l1)) # why size decreased to 120?
print(sys.getsizeof(t1)) # output 96
```

Comment: If these things actually *matter* to you, Python might not be the right language for your project. But 90+% of the time I see people ask questions like this, it really, really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression<sup>[1](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87740)</sup> in Python 3.9 that has been fixed<sup>[2](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/31816)</sup> in Python 3.10 (3.10.5).

> In Python v3.9+ there was a regression in the amount of used memory for
> list-literals, due to switching to using list_extend() to allocate memory for
> the new list to accomodate the literal elements. ...
>
> Prior to v3.9, the byte-code for making a list from a literal had the
> "BUILD_LIST" opcode with an explicit length argument, allowing allocation of
> the exact amount of memory needed for the literal. As of v3.9, the
> LIST_EXTEND opcode is used, instead. I believe the simplest way of restoring
> the old behavior is to change list_extend() to not overallocate when the list
> being extended currently has 0 elements.

Python 3.8 and Python 3.10:

```py
import sys
l1 = [1,2,3,4, "Quant Tading", "Python"]
t1 = (1,2,3,4, "Quant Tading", "Python")
print(sys.getsizeof(l1)) # output 104
print(sys.getsizeof(t1)) # output 88

import sys
l2 = [1,2,3,4, "Quant Tading", "Python", "xyz"]
t2 = (1,2,3,4, "Quant Tading", "Python", "xyz")
print(sys.getsizeof(l2)) # output 112
print(sys.getsizeof(t2)) # output 96
```

You can verify on https://www.python.org/shell/ (Python 3.10.5 when this answer was posted).

[1] [Regression in overallocation for literal list initialization in v3.9+ (issues/87740)](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87740)
[2] [bpo-39829: Optimize __len__() being called twice in the list() constructor (pull/31816)](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/31816)